# Rocket transformation give me only one row

Tags: python, time-series, transform

Need help on Rocket transformation

```
from sktime.transformations.panel.rocket import Rocket
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(
    n_samples=1000, # 1000 observations 
    n_features=5, # 5 total features
    n_informative=3, # 3 'useful' features
    n_classes=2, # binary target/label 
    random_state=999 # if you want the same results as mine
)

dataset = pd.DataFrame(X)
# give custom names to the features
dataset.columns = ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5']
# Now add the label as a column
dataset['y'] = y

rocket = Rocket(num_kernels=1000, random_state=0)
rocket.fit(dataset)
X_train_transform = rocket.transform(dataset)

X_train_transform.shape
#(1, 2000)
```

I try following this example
https://www.kaggle.com/code/vikram12301/rocket-time-series-classifier

I try Rocket transformation but turn out it gives me only 1 row.
I want to get Rocket transformation with 1000 observations.
Did i do anything wrong? really need help on this

Comment: Anything on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should transform your 2d df to a nested df. A nested df means that you bring all the recoreded values of ONE feature at different timesteps into a single cell of your df. So every row will be a timeseries of an entity (let say a company) and every column will be a feature (several columns are like sales, earnings, nb_employees). Upon nesting, every cell will be a TS of a feature for a specific company, like evolution of sales throughout the years for company A.

to invoke their built-in method use:

```
from sktime.datatypes._panel._convert import from_2d_array_to_nested
df_nested = from_2d_array_to_nested(df_2d)

trf = Rocket(num_kernels=1000) 
trf.fit(df_nested ) 
df_features = trf.transform(df_nested )
```

Note that if you have 1 feature examined for several companies, upon nesting you will have a nested df that consists of only 1 column.